# Something wrong with proof related to natural log?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $y: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Claim: If $y' = \frac{1}{x} $ then $y(ab) = y(a) + y(b)$

Proof: 
\begin{align}
y' &= \frac{1}{x}\\
\implies y(x) &= \int_1^x \frac{1}{z}  \ dz &\text{(fundamental theorem)}\\
\implies y(ab) &= \int_1^{ab} \frac{1}{z} \  dz \\
&= \int_1^a \frac{1}{z} dz + \int_a^{ab} \frac{1}{z} dz\\
&= y(a) + \int_1^b \frac{1}{t} \ dt &\text{(change of variables $z = at$)} \\
= y(a) + y(b)
\end{align}

However, $y = \ln(4x)$ is a counterexample to the above proof, since

$$y(ab) = \ln(4ab) = \ln(4) + \ln(a) + \ln(b) \ne \ln(16) + \ln(a) + \ln(b) = y(a) + y(b)$$

Comment: you assume $y(1)=0$ else the formula become $y(ab)-y(1)=y(a)-y(1)+y(b)-y(1)$

Comment: In your first step, why do you assume the starting point of your integral is $1$? We could also think about $\int_{17}^x{1\over z}dz$ ...

Comment: starting point could be anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y^{\prime}(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$, it follows that
$$\int_{1}^{x}y^{\prime}(t)\text{ d}t=y(x)-y(1)$$
You cannot drop the $y(1)$, since you don't have the assumption that $y(1) = 0$.

Comment: thanks, i see it now. I think that is what the other comments were hinting at too.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your very first step. The claim should be If $y' = \frac{1}{x}$, there exists a $y$ such that $y(ab) = y(a) + y(b)$. The claim as is does not imply $y(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{z} \, dz$.

Comment: doesn't that follow from the fundamental theorem?

Comment: @Auburn It does not.